# What method should I apply to solve this differential equation?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

What method should I use to solve the following differential equation?

$$\frac{dx}{dt}+x=\frac{dy}{dt}$$

Where $x,y$ are functions of $t\in[0,1].$

I know I should know how to do this, but it has been a while since I had to solve any ODE's.

Comment: is $y$ a function of x, or vice versa?

Comment: Both $y$ and $x$ are functions of $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: How to solve one equation with two functions!!!

Comment: @E.H.E: see my answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, no problem in the question if you assume a known function

Comment: @E.H.E: the expression with arbitrary $f$ is the general solution. Instead of an arbitrary integration constant, you have an arbitrary integration function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you have a single equation in two "unknowns".  Just as in algebraic equations, there is not a unique solution.  The best you can do is solve for one in terms of the other.  For example, to solve the equation $\frac{dx}{dt}+ x= f(t)$ where f(t) is a known function, we first solve $\frac{dx}{dt}+ x= 0$ getting $x(t)= Ce^{-t}$ with C a constant determined by some other condition.  Now, using the method of "undetermined coefficients", we seek a solution to the entire equation of the form $x(t)= u(t)e^{-t}$.  Then $\frac{dx}{dt}= e^{-t}\frac{du}{dt}- e^{-t}u$ so the equation becomes $\frac{dx}{dt}+ x= e^{-t}\frac{du}{dt}- e^{-t}u+ e^{-t}u= e^{-t}\frac{du}{dt}= f(t)$ so that $\frac{du}{dt}= e^{t}f(t)$ and we can solve for u by integrating both sides with respect to u: $u(t)= \int e^t f(t)dt$.

In this particular problem, $f(t)= \frac{dy}{dt}$ so $u(t)= \int e^t \frac{dy}{dt}  dt$ which can be integrated "by parts".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $x(t)$ is known,

$$y=x+\int x\,dt+C.$$

If $y(t)$ is known,

$$\frac{d(e^tx)}{dt}=e^t\left(x+\frac{dx}{dt}\right)$$ hence

$$x=e^{-t}\left(\int y\,e^tdy+C\right).$$

If neither is known, take any differentiable function $f$ and

$$\begin{cases}x(t)=\dfrac{df}{dt}(t),\\y(t)=f(t)+\dfrac{df}{dt}(t).\end{cases}$$